# SQL INNER JOIN tables syntax

Tags: sql, database, inner-join

I'm try to do a sql query where i have a class id, and with this class id i need to get the user id, of which the user id is then used on another table to get the users information such as first name, and last name.

This is what my tables look like:

[image: Table Name: class]
**Table Name:** classlist

[image: Table Name: student] 
**Table Name:** student

The relationship between class.UID and student.UID is setup correctly.

This is what i've tried thus far but doesn't work (i'm new to PHP and SQL):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN classlist ON student.UID=classlist.UID WHERE classlist.ClassID='$classID'");
```

What would be the proper sql syntax for this query?

**Additional Notes**
ClassID originates from a table called class and UID originates from a table call student, both have their relationships setup.

Comment: did it throw any exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working fiddle**:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6308d/2

The names of your table are wrong (according to your post)

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN class ON student.UID=class.UID AND class.ClassID='$classID'");
```

Also, I changed `Where` to `And` as it's a join condition

Comment: you are joining using `INNER JOIN` so it will have no difference if you add the condition in the `where` clause or in the `ON` clause.

Comment: @JW isn't the correct way to use `And` in this case since the condition in on the joined table?

Comment: not that it is wrong but the idea is the same. only it matters if you are using `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: would it be easier for me to just create two queries of which the first query gets the UID from the classlist table, then i do another query that uses the UID on the student table to get the information i need?

Comment: In this particular case, it might be. The right thing to do would be to add another table called `class` that would just have `classID` and `className` fields, and then you could do a proper join.

Comment: i do have a table that has that information, i forgot to provide that information initially. I have a table called class from which ClassID originates from, and i have a student table from which UID originates from. This classlist table is the table that should join them together, if i'm doing this correctly.

Comment: @Staleyr I'm honestly not sure what problem you are having with the above query - are there any results being returned? Are they the correct ones? This seems like a very simple relationship where the JOIN should work

Comment: *slaps forehead* Thank you Evan, the sql query was correct, there was a problem with my $classID that i get from the previous page and use in my query, that's why i was getting no results. It's difficult for you guys to help when i'm not even doing things right myself! Thanks for your help.